# How can I decrypt data encrypted by Node's deprecated createCipher, in Ruby?

Tags: node.js, ruby, encryption, cryptography

I have some legacy data, encrypted in Node, which I need to decrypt in Ruby.

The problem is, the data was encrypted with a now deprecated method, [`createCipher`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options). This method uses a password to perform encryption. It has been replaced by [`createCipheriv`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options), which requires a 32 byte key and a 16 byte initialization vector.

In Node, I can decrypt the string with the similarly deprecated [`createDecipher`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipher_algorithm_password_options), which also accepts a password. However, I'm not aware of any equivalent method in Ruby, which makes sense, since these methods are now known to be insecure and are deprecated.

Ruby's OpenSSL AES Cipher correctly requires a 32 byte key and 16 byte IV like the newer `createCipheriv`, but I don't have either of these, only the original password I used with `createCipher`.

How can I get `createCipher`/`createDecipher`-like behavior in Ruby?

Specifically, given the following JavaScript...

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const cipher = crypto.createCipher("aes-256-cbc", 'secret password');
cipherText = cipher.update('dummy string', "utf8", "hex") + cipher.final("hex");

console.log(cipherText); // f3051259f83c7ca2ac012a396c4c0848
```

... how can I use the password `'secret password'` to decrypt the string `'f3051259f83c7ca2ac012a396c4c0848'` and arrive back at the input value `'dummy string'` in Ruby?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The underlying algorithm, aes256, requires a 32 bit key and 16 bit initialization vector, regardless of the interface provided by higher level abstractions like `createCipher`. Under the hood, it *must* be producing a 32 bit key and 16 bit initialization vector, derived from the input password.

`createCipher` does this by repeatedly MD5 hashing on the input password to produce a byte array, from which it extracts the 32 byte key and a 16 byte initialization vector. It was deprecated because this is not a secure way of producing a random IV (indeed the IV it produces is completely deterministic).

This happens down inside the C source of Node, in [/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/evp/evp_key.c](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8c9aaacb333a0223243eda9b3551dbf26fdb260a/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/evp/evp_key.c#L74).

This function has quite a few arguments, but when used to generate a key/iv for `createCipher('aes-256-cbc', 'password')`, this method is invoked [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/fc50e6bcc81e4b34f4f3f3fe494b79200ae22efb/src/node_crypto.cc#L3899), with the following arguments:

```
const EVP_CIPHER *type,    // "aes-256-cbc"
const EVP_MD *md,          // EVP_md5()
const unsigned char *salt, // null, unused
const unsigned char *data, // "password"
int datal,                 // 8, length of "password"
int count,                 // 1, unused
unsigned char *key,        // output key buffer
unsigned char *iv,         // output iv buffer
```

This method must produce 48 total bytes (32 for the key, and 16 for the IV) and it does so by first running `hash = md5(password)`, producing 16 bytes.

Now, for each subsequent set of 16 bytes, it concatenates the previous 16 bytes with the `password`, and hashes it again: `hash = md5(hash + password)`.

Effectively bytes...

- 0 to 16 generated via `md5(password)`
- 17 to 32 generated via `md5(md5(password) + password)`
- 33 to 48 genearted via `md5(md5(md5(password) + password) + password)`.

We can implement the same in Ruby to derive the correct key and IV to decrypt a given string via a password:

```rb
require 'digest'
require 'openssl'

def decrypt(cipher_text, password)
  bytes = [ Digest::MD5.digest(password) ]
  bytes << Digest::MD5.digest(bytes.last + password)
  bytes << Digest::MD5.digest(bytes.last + password)

  bytes = bytes.join

  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
  cipher.decrypt

  cipher.key = bytes[0...32]
  cipher.iv = bytes[32...48]

  # OpenSSL deals in raw bytes, not the hex-encoded representation
  # 'f3051259f83c7ca2ac012a396c4c0848' => "\xF3\x05\x12Y\xF8<|\xA2\xAC\x01*9lL\bH"
  cipher_text = cipher_text.unpack('a2' * (cipher_text.length / 2)).map(&:hex).pack('c*')

  cipher.update(cipher_text) + cipher.final
end

decrypt('f3051259f83c7ca2ac012a396c4c0848', 'secret password') # => 'dummy string'
```

For completeness, here is the equivalent `encrypt` method, which will allow data encrypted in Ruby to be decrypted in Node's deprecate `createDecipher`:

```rb
 def encrypt(plain_text, password)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
  cipher.encrypt

  bytes = [ Digest::MD5.digest(password) ]
  bytes << Digest::MD5.digest(bytes.last + password)
  bytes << Digest::MD5.digest(bytes.last + password)

  bytes = bytes.join

  cipher.key = bytes[0...32]
  cipher.iv = bytes[32...48]

  cipher_text = cipher.update(plain_text) + cipher.final

  # Produce a hex representation
  # "\xF3\x05\x12Y\xF8<|\xA2\xAC\x01*9lL\bH" => 'f3051259f83c7ca2ac012a396c4c0848'
  cipher_text.unpack('C*').map { |byte| byte.to_s(16) }.map { |str| str.rjust(2, "0") }.join
end

encrypt('dummy string', 'secret password') # => "f3051259f83c7ca2ac012a396c4c0848"
```