# How does the Node.JS crypto module produce a key and an initialization vector when the deprecated `crypto.createCipher` function is used?

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes

I have inherited a database where some fields were encrypted by legacy code.

The code used the (now deprecated) [crypto.createCipher](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options) function that Node.js provided. This function expects to be passed a plaintext password, rather than a key and initialization vector. The documentation suggests that a key and IV are derived (somehow) from the provided password.

I have the password that was used, but would like to decrypt the data in another application, written in a language that uses a standard key/IV combination to initialize an AES cipher (Python 3).

Looking at the Node.js codebase, in [cipher.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/crypto/cipher.js), it is not at all apparent to me how this is being done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see after writing this, that the question has a ruby-specific answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57068729/how-can-i-decrypt-data-encrypted-by-nodes-deprecated-createcipher-in-ruby) that I could not find when searching. I have decided to create a more general-purpose question and answer here to increase its visability.

Node computes the key and value using the [`md5` hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5).

A 32-byte key is produced with the following algorithm (shown in pseudocode):

```
Let A = md5(password)
Let B = md5(concatenate(A, password))
Let Key = concatenate(A,B)
```

A 16 byte initialization vector is then produced with:

```
Let IV = md5(concatenate(key, password))
```

Comment: For the next person who happens across this, I think there's a mistake above. It should be:

`Let IV = md5(concatenate(B, password))`